# Why is this comma usage incorrect?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I know that this sentence is grammatically incorrect, and I know of a few ways to fix the problem, but I don't actually know why it's incorrect and that bothers me.

> Climate change is a biological threat, if not constrained it will be a key danger to health and life on Earth.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a [comma splice](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

Comment: I'd use a full-stop after the word threat. It would also help to hammer home the statement 'Climate change is a biological threat'

Comment: Comma is incorrect because a semi-colon is what should have been there.

Comment: Jordan, You seem to be new here, have you visited ell.stackexchange.com for English Language Learners?

Comment: Hi Kris - I'm actually a native English speaker. I just don't have particularly good grammatical knowledge (which is unfortunate), but I'm doing what I can to learn more. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

As @JanusBahsJacquet stated in the comments above, this is an example of a [comma splice.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/runons.htm)  You have used a comma to join two independent clauses.  Instead you could use either a period, or a semicolon.

> Climate change is a biological threat; if not constrained it will be a
>   key danger to health and life on Earth.

OR

> Climate change is a biological threat.  If not constrained it will be
>   a key danger to health and life on Earth.

Alternatively, you could add a conjunction (and, but, for, nor, yet, or, so) after the comma.

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/indep_clauses.htm

Answer (score -1):

Climate change is the primary clause of this sentence. If the primary clause is followed by a dependent clause, then a comma is not required. If the vice-versa happens, then a comma is required. Consider the following examples.

**If it rains today**, I will not go to the fair.
I will not go to the fair **if it rains today**.

**When Kasun and I were at home**, our friends were playing carom.
Our friends were playing carom **when Kasun and I were at home**.

The highlighted clauses in the above sentences are dependent clauses because they cannot stand alone.

Comment: The sentence you _could_ be analysing this way is: _If it is not constrained, it will be a key danger to health and life on Earth._ And it needs setting off from _Climate change is a biological threat_ – by a semicolon, or as a separate sentence. The 'it is' may then be omitted, as here.